# Redirect doesn't update URI parameter value (keeps the old one from the redirected page)

Tags: php, redirect

I have a PHP header redirect on my page and it might not be working as expected. I <s>have</s> **had<sup>(1)</sup>** a Bitcoin faucet with referral system and I have a reflink that receives most of the traffic, but the address is no longer valid so I wanted to redirect all visitors from that reflink to a new one.

I use this in index.php at the very top:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/?r=oldReferral')
{
    header("Location: http://example.com/?r=newReferral");
    die();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- etc -->
```

This does redirect to the new referral URI, but the old address is still getting all the referral payouts.

The redirect being at the very top with `die();` right after should prevent any other scripts on that page from executing and go straight to the new page where the scripts will execute, right? But since the old address is still being rewarded, I would think that some scripts still manage to execute before the redirect happens.

<s>Why does it keep the old url in memory (or wherever) after redirecting to the new url?</s>

Why does the payout script on the new URI uses the parameter from the old one, when it shouldn't even get saved/cached. Is it possible that this redirect method still allows some code execution before it leaves the page?

**Is there some sure way of redirect that would guarantee that absolutely nothing from the old URL/URI somehow finds its way to the new one?**

One thing that just came to my mind... The faucet script I've been using most likely uses `$_SESSION` to store whatever it needs to store. Is it possible that the old ref URI gets saved in the session (or some other web storage system) and because the redirect happens before any other scripts (that could otherwise possibly ie. maybe clear the sessions), the old value just gets carried-over to the new URI?

---

<sup>(1) Technically I still have the site, but haven't touched it in years so please bear that in mind if you'd like me to provide some more details or code samples.</sup>

Comment: Because the old url still exists.

Comment: @Geshode I tried redirecting via completely different site (oldURL ----> differentSite --- (directly) ---> newURL) and it still behaves the same.